# Flow Diagram of Formulae to Create Algorithm - Does this Method have a Name? Does it have Software?

Tags: terminology

This is a diagram that I recently created to help me solve a series of formulae in order to create an algorithm for a database program.  For some reason I just couldn't visualise all the elements, so I decided to write it out to see what I could come up with.

I'm not sure if it's the sort of diagram that another person could easily follow, but it was useful to clarify my thinking, and it just follows two simple rules:

- Arrows leaving an equation carry the evaluated value of an equation (the single LHS term)
- Arrows entering an equation represent one of the terms in the formula (usually on the RHS - a slight rearrangement of terms could have made this a hard rule)

Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to post an image, but here's a link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4klk.png

- Yellow items are givens
- Green items are trivial formulae
- Blue items are the slightly more difficult formulae that I wanted to determine
- Magenta items are check-sums to ensure the results can be trusted

I'm not asking about the algorithm - it's currently working like a charm.  The chart helped me a lot.

What I want to know is, is there a particular name for this kind of method of charting formulae/algorithms (or is there something similar that does have a name), and is there any software that can do it specifically?